# Assesrtion Error in Junit test

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermock, easymock

I have a function which accepts the JSON String and returns me the string by calling a service
I am using google JSON builder

```
public String getserviceresult()
{
Gson gson = new Gson();
HashMap h =new HashMap()
//Adding some attributes in hashmap

h.add("Id",request.getid());
h.add("sessionid",SessionUtils.getSessionId());
String expectedstring =service.getString(gson.toJson(hashmap))
}
```

I have unit test written for this which was working succcessfully
First i already mocked SessionUtils class and serviceclient classes using Powermock.Now to test function getserviceresult()

```
public validjsonstring="{\"id\":\"customerid\",\"sessionid\":,\"somessionid\"}"
public testfunc()
{
  expect(service.getString(validjsonstring)).andReturn("somestring").anyTimes();
PowerMock.replayAll();
assert("somestring",getserviceresult());
Powermock.verifyAll();

}
```

This code was working fine.The Problem is now when i am changing the key in Hashmap from "sessionid" to "sessionId" the unit tests fails giving me assertion error and getserviceresult() function returns null.There is nothing wrong with service because when i ran that function without running unit test it gives me proper result what iexpect but when i change key in hashmap for sessionid to sessionId the mocked service call fails and return null

Any ideas why this weird error

ERROR:Assertion error getserviceresult() expected "somestring" but returned null when i change sessionid  to sessionId

Comment: are you changing the key only in one place ie source code or test class alone. case might be a concern in your case

Comment: why, you have to change the "sessionid" string? then, which sessionid did you change? the "h.add("sessionid"" or the "validjsonstring="{\"id\":\"customerid\",\"sessionid\"" ? I suppose the first one, but have you cahnged the second one too?

Comment: Could you provide the code of which fails ?

Comment: Saurabh i changed the session id at both places                                1)In getserviceresult function and validjsonstring variable h.add("sessionid",SessionUtils.getSessionId()); changed to h.add("sessionId",SessionUtils.getSessionId());  and  tesfunc i have edited validjsonstring variable to public validjsonstring="{\"id\":\"customerid\",\"sessionId\":,\"somessionid\"}" which the service requires

Comment: Did you change SessionUtils.getSessionId(), to return something other than somessionid like somessionId?